# Prevent apps from using wifi without VPN

Tags: network, wifi, security, vpn

When I travel and am connecting to public wireless networks (or, really, any wireless network I don't control), I use a VPN (either L2TP with the built-in networking support or OpenVPN with Viscosity).  What I'd like to do, though, is prevent any applications from using the unsecured wireless network in the few seconds between connecting to the wireless and getting the VPN connection up.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: The duplicate message below is slightly incorrect.  No need to ask a new question if your situation isn't duplicated. Just edit details into the body to differentiate your setup or problem from past questions and we can reopen this.